# Calculate percentage between two entity fields in Drupal using Computed Field Module

Tags: entities

I am trying to calculate a `%` of two entity fields in Drupal 7 using Computed Field module.

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_accounts_payable_bs'))) /
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_customer_deposits_bs')));
```

Display:

```
$display_output = number_format($entity_field_item['value'] , 1 , '.' , ',');
```

Current the value I get is ".20" But I want it "20.0"

Comment: Your number_format parameters would produce 20.0 but that's hundred times of what you're now getting. So are you referring to the math or the format or both? Obvious answer would be multiplying by 100.

Comment: Hi Kari, well both, I know that I need to calculate it by multiplying by "100", just don't know how to do it with PHP and the Computed Field module.

Comment: Simply like this: $display_output = 100 * number_format($entity_field_item['value'], 1, '.', ',');

Comment: Hold on, the calculation code has a division slash at the end of the first row, and he is displaying a value that is not in the calculation. Maybe there is more to it than arithmetic operators. John, print() function is very helpful when trying to get Computed Field working.

Comment: Oops, don't try to multiply the result of number_format, that won't work, sorry. See my answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

First print_r($data) in your Output code text area so you can see what you can work with. Depending on what you have, your Output code is going to look something like this:

```
$percent = 100 * $data->field_accounts_payable_bs['0']['raw']['value'] / $data->field_customer_deposits_bs['0']['raw']['value'];

print(number_format($percent, 1, '.', ','));
```

Comment: Kari, 

I tried this code but no results field is NULL.

I tried the output of **$display_output = (number_format($percent, 1, '.', ','));** and it displayed **0.0**

But the calculation should result in 8.3 using my previous method, it would display .083.

Doe sit make a difference that I am using the entity module?

Comment: Try printing those fields individually.

Comment: Sorry Kari, I don't understand. I am just a novice.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out! In order to calculate a percentage from two Entity fields with the Computed Fields Module you have to do the following;

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_accounts_payable_bs'))) /
array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_customer_deposits_bs'))) * 100;
```

For the display use:

```
$display_output = number_format($entity_field_item['value'] , 1 , '.' , ',');
```

Thank you all for your help!